# Формирование словаря с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.

---

Есть объекты с полями вида: (Книга, Тема, Автор и т.д.)
Вопрос в том, как в цикле по объектам сформировать словарь(может быть что-то другое), где первые несколько полей одинаковые, а остальные разные, т.е. чтобы в словаре не было повторений, а было что-то вроде этого

```
{'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1, 'authors': {'authorID': 2, 'authorID': 3}}
```

Задача из нескольких объектов с одинаковой книгой и темой и разными авторами сформировать один словарь.

Comment: Приведите пример исходных данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего использовать в качестве ключа кортеж из уникальных полей:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = [
    {'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1, 'foo': 1},
    {'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1, 'bar': 2},
    {'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1, 'some': 3},
    {'bookID': 2, 'themeID': 1, 'bar': 1},
    {'bookID': 2, 'themeID': 1, 'foo': 2},
    {'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 2, 'some': 1}
]

books = defaultdict(dict)
for item in items:
    copy = item.copy()
    books[(copy.pop('bookID'), copy.pop('themeID'))].update(copy)
```

В результате в `books` будет:

```
{   (1, 1): {   'bar': 2, 'foo': 1, 'some': 3},
    (1, 2): {   'some': 1},
    (2, 1): {   'bar': 1, 'foo': 2}}
```

Если же нужно, что бы имена полей ключей сохранились, то можно поместить в кортеж и их:

```
for item in items:    
    copy = item.copy()
    key = ((k, copy.pop(k)) for k in ('bookID', 'themeID'))
    books[tuple(key)].update(copy)
```

Тогда в будущем можно будет использовать их так:

```
for key, val in books.items():
    key = dict(key)
    print(key['bookID'])
    print(val.get('some'))
    # ...
```

Или так:

```
print( books[{'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 2}.items()]['some'] )
```

И еще один вариант использовать [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

books = groupby(items, lambda i: (i['bookID'], i['themeID']))
```

В результате получится:

```
for k,v in books:
    print(k, list(v))

# ((1, 1), [{'foo': 1, 'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1}, {'bar': 2, 'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1}, {'some': 3, 'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 1}])
# ((2, 1), [{'bar': 1, 'bookID': 2, 'themeID': 1}, {'foo': 2, 'bookID': 2, 'themeID': 1}])
# ((1, 2), [{'some': 1, 'bookID': 1, 'themeID': 2}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего оформить вложенным массивом. Или я не понял вопроса ?

```
{'book_id':1,
 'authors':['author1','author2','author3'],
}
```

Comment: Это понятно. Проблема в том, что не ясно как в цикле определять повторение "Книги" и "Темы" и потом уже записывать или дописывать автора.

Comment: Да примерчик входных и выходных данных в студию )